# How can I smooth jagged RoundedCornerShape in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, rounded-corners

I'm trying to round off the top two corners of a Box, and keep the bottom two corners rectangular.

If I use

```
RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 8.dp, topEnd = 8.dp, bottomStart = 8.dp, bottomEnd = 8.dp)
```

or

```
RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
```

the corners are perfectly smooth.

If I use

```
RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 8.dp, topEnd = 8.dp, bottomStart = 0.dp, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
```

they are not. They are rounded but with low resolution/jagged.

What i found out is that both variants end up using this class

```
class RoundedCornerShape(
    topStart: CornerSize,
    topEnd: CornerSize,
    bottomEnd: CornerSize,
    bottomStart: CornerSize
) : CornerBasedShape(
    topStart = topStart,
    topEnd = topEnd,
    bottomEnd = bottomEnd,
    bottomStart = bottomStart
)
```

so they should behave the same way.

Has anyone had the same experience or can help me out here?

Comment: I have at least found the cause why it occurs. 
I am developing for a device with Android version 8.1. When I emulate a device with e.g. Android 13 the error does not occur and all corners are smooth.